# How do you track third party services SSL certificates?

Tags: testing, validation, ssl

Recently [Windows Azure Storage SSL certificate unexpectedly expired](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15033020/57428) and since a lot of dependent services defaulted to "refuse to connect to a site with expired SSL certificate" that became a serious problem.

Now the SSL certificate of any web service can be retrieved by anyone at any time for validation. The picture is from the linked to question:

[image: cert expired]

So it means that the information was available at all times to "anyone it might concern" and any user of the service could have noticed the upcoming expiration and for example post a message on Microsoft forums before it was too late.

However I can't find any information about how such cases are typically handled except [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2509854/57428) for doing that in code.

Is there any kind of best practice for validating third party services SSL certificates? What tools are typically used?

Comment: Interesting read (pdf): [The Most Dangerous Code in the World:
Validating SSL Certiﬁcates in Non-Browser Software](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are one such user, and run a Nagios/Icinga installation already anyway, there's [a check to warn *before* a certificate expires](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/HTTP/check_ssl_certificate/details).

This is what we use at work.

You'll “just” have to enumerate (by virtual host / server hostname) all those external services your things depend on (and keep that list up-to-date, which may not be as easy as it sounds).

Answer (score 1):

I have a [Ruby library I'm open-sourcing](https://github.com/dogweather/rspec-webservice_matchers) to enable this with TDD – Test Driven Devops. I'm making a Python version as well. Here's how it looks, testing a web app in Ruby:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'My app' do
  it 'is configured for ssl' do
    # New-style RSpec syntax
    expect('www.myapp.com').to have_a_valid_cert

    # Old-style RSpec syntax
    'www.weblaws.org'.should have_a_valid_cert
  end
end
```

My idea is that these tests can be run periodically, say every five minutes, and notify on error.